# Django drf-spectacular - Can you exclude specific paths?

Tags: django, swagger, drf-spectacular

We have a bunch of api's with different versions in urls.py, eg

- api/v1
- api/v2
- api/v3

.  We want to implement swagger with drf-spectacular, but we only want to expose api/v3 endpoints.

Is there a way to do this?  I cannot make sense of the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: there seems to be a way in drf-yasg with get_schema_view "patterns".   I don't think this is translated to drf-spectacular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out.  Copied the custom preprocessing hook function, changed the pass statement to filter what I did not require in the endpoints, then mapped the location of the file and function in my spectacular settings for preprocessed hooks.

Answer (score 16):

This works for me:

```
def preprocessing_filter_spec(endpoints):
    filtered = []
    for (path, path_regex, method, callback) in endpoints:
        # Remove all but DRF API endpoints
        if path.startswith("/api/"):
            filtered.append((path, path_regex, method, callback))
    return filtered
```

In settings:

```
"PREPROCESSING_HOOKS": ["common.openapi.preprocessing_filter_spec"],
```

Answer (score 8):

You could also exclude it with the following:

```
    from drf_spectacular.utils import extend_schema
    ...
    
    @extend_schema(
        exclude=True
    )
    @api_view(['GET'])
    def my_view(request):
        # your code here
```

Or you could exclude a whole viewset:

```
    @extend_schema_view(
        list=extend_schema(exclude=True),
        retrieve=extend_schema(exclude=True),
        create=extend_schema(exclude=True),
        update=extend_schema(exclude=True),
        partial_update=extend_schema(exclude=True),
        destroy=extend_schema(exclude=True)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Detail:**

Create a file in same directory where setting.py is. Let's say file name is *excluded_path.py*

**1- Add to excluded_path.py:**
Here's the schema is path we don't want to show in output of docs.

```
def custom_preprocessing_hook(endpoints):
   filtered = []
   for (path, path_regex, method, callback) in endpoints:
       if "schema" not in path:
           filtered.append((path, path_regex, method, callback))
   return filtered
```

**2- settings.py**

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
   'PREPROCESSING_HOOKS': ["djapi.excluded_path.custom_preprocessing_hook"]
}
```